# Phyton: Problem with .iloc function to get individual odd and even rows

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I'm currently trying to transcribe my R code to Python, but I'm facing a problem.

My R code:

```
library(sidrar)

table_nameUrl= read.csv(file= "Data.txt", header= F, sep= "\n")
table_size= length(table_nameUrl[[1]])
sequence= seq(1, table_size, by= 2)
for (i in sequence) {
  csv_name= table_nameUrl[[1]][i]
  csv_url= table_nameUrl[[1]][i+1]
  last_url= "/n3/all/n6/in%20n3%2028"
  file_name= paste(csv_name,".csv",sep="")
  url= paste(csv_url, last_url, sep="")
  table= get_sidra(api= url)
  write.csv(table, file= file_name, row.names = F)
}
```

My Python code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import rpy2.robjects.packages as rp
from rpy2 import robjects as ro
from rpy2.robjects.conversion import localconverter as lc

utils = rp.importr('utils')
utils.chooseCRANmirror(ind=1)
utils.install_packages("sidrar")
sidrar = rp.importr("sidrar")
    
table_nameUrl = pd.read_csv("Data.txt", sep=";", header= None)
table_size = len(table_nameUrl)
sequence = np.arange(1, table_Size, 2)
for i in sequence:
 csv_name = table_nameUrl.iloc[::2]
 csv_url = table_nameUrl.iloc[1::2]
 last_url = "/n3/all/n6/in%20n3%2028"
 file_name = (csv_name + ".csv")
 url = (csv_url + last_url)
 with lc(ro.default_converter + pr.converter):
  file_nameC = ro.conversion.py2rpy(file_name)
  url_c = ro.conversion.py2rpy(url)
 ro.globalenv['fileName'] = file_nameC
 ro.globalenv['url'] = url_c
 ro.r('table= get_sidra(api= url)')
 ro.r('write.csv(table, file= fileName, row.names = F)
```

My problem is:

I'm using `rpy2` in Python to get R's `sidrar` package.
I'm not using native Python packages because I need to auto generate a lot of CSVs files with the Sidra API's URLs from `Data.txt`, so `sidrar` is the best one to do it.

In R, I can get odd and even lines of `Data.txt` with `[[1]][i]` and `[[1]][i+1]`, so if I print `csv_name` (odd rows) and `csv_url` (even rows) the output will be:

`csv_name`:

```
'Panu 2.1.1, 2.1.5'
```

`csv_url`:

```
'/t/2093/p/2000,2010/v/93/c86/2776,2777,2778,2779,2780,2781/c2/0,4,5/c1/1,2/'
```

It only takes the content of the one row (so, I can get line by line with `for` loop), it doesn't transform it into another table or dataframe. What makes it possible the generation dozens of CSV files with different names and URLs.

But in Python, I changed `[[1]][i]` and `[[1]][i+1]` to `.iloc[::2]` and `.iloc[1::2]` to get odd and even lines.

So when I try to print `csv_name` and `csv_url` the output is:

`csv_name`:

| 0 |
| --- |
| **0** ㅤ Panu 2.1.1, 2.1.5 |
| **2** ㅤ Panu 5.1.1, 5.1.2, 5.1.3, 5.1.4, 5.1.5, 5.1.6,... |
| **4** ㅤ Panu 5.1.8 |
| **6** ㅤ Panu 5.1.11 |
| **8** ㅤ Panu 5.1.12, 5.1.13, 5.1.14, 5.1.15, 5.1.16, 5... |

`csv_url`:

| 0 |
| --- |
| **1** ㅤ/t/2093/p/2000,2010/v/93/c86/2776,2777,2778,27... |
| **3** ㅤ/t/1612/p/2013,2014,2015,2016,2017/v/109,216,2... |
| **5** ㅤ/t/839/p/2013,2014,2015,2016,2017/v/109,216,21... |
| **7** ㅤ /t/5457/p/2013,2014,2015,2016,2017/v/8331,216,... |
| **9** ㅤ /t/1613/p/2013,2014,2015,2016,2017/v/2313,216,... |

The `.iloc` generates two tables with all `Data.txt`'s even or odd lines.
So when I try to generate the CSVs with `get_sidra` the error appears:

```
Error in get_sidra(api = url) : 
  The 'api' argument must be a character vector
```

**Thanks in advance if someone can help me!**

Comment: [a:b:c] is a slicing operation in python. It will return every c th element from a included to b excluded. You only want one line at a time.  So just get the rows with .iloc[i] and .iloc[i+1] .

Comment: @kubatucka, thank you so much, you went straight to the point!